# How to remove object from Autopopulate list in spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new to spring + hibernate. When I add a customer and its destinations (one to many relationship), everything is fine.  But when I update the customer's destination, all previous destinations remain in the database with a null customer foreign key.

Suppose I insert 4 destinations a, b, c, d.  After updating the customer, I insert x, y. Then it stores total 6 destinations: a, b, c, d with null references and x, y with customer references.

Here is my code:

**1). Customer Entity**

Has one-to-many relationship with destination and relationship is unidirectional.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customers")
@Proxy(lazy=false)
public class CustomerEntity {   

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String description; 
    private String panNo;
    private String cstNo;
    private String vatNo;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    public List<DestinationsEntity> destination = new AutoPopulatingList<DestinationsEntity>(DestinationsEntity.class);

    //getter and setters
}
```

**2). Destination Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "destinations")
@Proxy(lazy = false)
public class DestinationsEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id")
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name="destination")
  private String destination;
  // getter and setter
}
```

**1). AddCustomer.jsp**

This code for adding more destinations in Autopopulate list

```
        <div id="destination_container">
                <div><textarea row="3" col="5" class="destination_address" name= "destination[${0}].destination" placeholder="Please enter address"></textarea></div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){

                    var index = 1;
                /*
                * Add more destination
                */

                $('#add_more_destination').click(function(){
                        $('#destination_container').append('<div><textarea row="3" col="5" class="destination_address" name= "destination[${"'+index+'"}].destination" placeholder="Please enter address"></textarea><span class="remove_dest">*</span></div>');
                        index++;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

**2). updateCustomer.jsp**

All destinations added by customer is show here and he/she can be change destinations(like before inserted pune, mumbai , banglore) now updating destinations( delhi, punjab)

```
        <c:set var="index" scope="page" value="${fn:length(destinationss)}"/>
        <c:forEach items="${destinationss}" var="dest" varStatus="i">   
        <div>
            <textarea class="destination_address" name= "destination[${i.index}].destination" placeholder="Please enter address">${dest.destination}</textarea><span class="remove_dest">*</span>
        </div>  
        </c:forEach>
        <button type ="button" id="add_more_destination">Add More Destinations</button>

        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){

                /*
                * Add a destination
                */

                var index = ${index};
                $('#add_more_destination').click(function(){
                        $('#destination_container').append('<div><textarea row="3" col="5" class="destination_address" name=destination["'+index+'"].destination placeholder="Please enter address"></textarea><span class="remove_dest">*</span></div>');  
                        alert(index);
                        index++;
                });
        </script>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addCustomerForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addCustomerForm(ModelMap map) {
    return "master/addCustomer";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/addCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addCustomer(@ModelAttribute(value = "customer") CustomerEntity customer,BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
    customerService.addCustomer(customer);
    return "redirect:/customer";
}
```

**Update Customer**

This is new thing I tried last night. Problem is solved partially.

```
@ModelAttribute
public void updateOperation(HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap map) {
    if(null !=request.getParameter("id"))
       map.addAttribute("customer1", customerService.findOne(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"))));
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateCustomerForm/{customerId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateCustomerForm(@PathVariable("customerId") Integer customerId, ModelMap map, HttpServletRequest request) {
       CustomerEntity customerEntity = customerService.findOne(customerId);
       map.addAttribute("customer", customerEntity);
                map.addAttribute("destinationss",customerEntity.getDestination());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/updateCustomer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateCustomer(@ModelAttribute(value = "customer1")CustomerEntity customer1,BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
       customerService.updateCustomer(customer1);
       return "redirect:/customer";
    }
}
```

**1). CustomerServiceImpl**

```
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService{

   @Autowired
   private CustomerDao customerDao;

   @Override
   @Transactional
   public void addCustomer(CustomerEntity customer) {
      customerDao.addCustomer(customer);
   }    

   @Override
   @Transactional
   public CustomerEntity findOne(Integer id){
      return customerDao.findOne(id);
   }

   @Override
   @Transactional
   public void updateCustomer(CustomerEntity customerEntity){
      if (null != customerEntity) {
        customerDao.updateCustomer(customerEntity);     
      }
   }
}
```

**2).CustomerDaoImpl**

```
public class CustomerDaoImpl implements CustomerDao{
   @Autowired
   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   @Override
   @Transactional
   public void addCustomer(CustomerEntity customer){
      this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(customer);
   }

   @Override
   public CustomerEntity findOne(Integer id){
      return (CustomerEntity) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(CustomerEntity.class, id);
   }

   @Override
   @Transactional
   public void updateCustomer(CustomerEntity customerEntity){
         if (null != customerEntity) {
                   this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(customerEntity);
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear,  please explain it properly

Comment: actually i have relationship one to many 1 customer having multiple destination. when i am saving 1 customer with 4 destination all working properly. but when tring to update customer object then previously save destinations forign key change to null and new destinations save in database

Comment: solution is to get the destinations for the customer and store it in a Set, then add your new destinations to the set and then do the update. Now Hibernate will take care of the relationship. If you are not doing this then hibernate assumes that you are trying to remove the older destinations and adding new destinations, so that is the reason the foreign keys are removed in destination table for those old entires.

Comment: it is working fine when i am adding new destinations in set but when reducing destinations then result generated wrong as i explain before. i think when @modelAttribute create new object of customer in updateCustomer thats why problem is generating. but not sure

Comment: you want to add new destinations to the existing customer right?

Comment: `2. update customer` code is not complete in your question, where is the code related to Hibernate, where you are doing hibernate update operation?

Comment: i want to do both the thing adding new destinations also or some times remove. in removing case all things goes wrong

Comment: this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(customerEntity);

Comment: this is daoImpl method where i am updating customer

Comment: Here DaoImpl added in updated code

Comment: I Will add answer, try that and see if it works

Comment: @Javed Shhaikh As I was editing your post, I noticed that you have "destinationss" added to the ModelMap.  Not sure whether this is what you want or whether it is a typo.

Comment: @bphilipnyc as you can see it is list of destinations i added in updateCustomer method to show on front End..

Comment: @Javed Shhaikh Ok, I see it now

Comment: after that i have line  ---> return "master/updateCustomer"; actually i miss it. all goes write now but when i am inserting more destinations than previous in update customer form then everything working fine but when inserting less than previous then Destinations table does not updated.

Comment: @bphilipnyc check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994015/removing-items-from-springs-autopopulatinglist . same as my issue. nothing is change

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Spring will give you new Customer entity, so I guess the Destination entities in this Customer is empty initially. So in your update operation you are just adding some new Destination entities and then adding them to customer as per your code.

So in this case, the customer entity is having only the new Destination objects where as the already existing Destination entities which were mapped earlier are not present in your Customer entity.

To fix the issue, first get the Customer entity from database, then this entity will have the set of Destination objects. Now to this Customer you can add new Destination objects and also update the existing Destination objects if needed then ask Hibernate to do the update operation. In this case Hibernate can see your earlier destination objects and also the new destination objects and based on that it will run the insert & update queries.

The code looks something like this:

```
// First get the customer object from database:
Customer customer = (Customer) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(Customer.class, customerId);

// Now add your destination objects, if you want you can update the existing destination entires here.

for (int i = 0; i < destinationAddrs.length; i++) {
                    DestinationsEntity destination = new DestinationsEntity();
                    destination.setDestination(destinationAddrs[i]);
                                customer.getDestinationEntity().add(destination);


                }

// Then do the update operation    
this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(customer);
```

Comment: @modelAttribute always give me new object of customer how can i replcae it with persist object .. any solution for it. or working example.

Comment: how can i load persist object instead of new customer object

Comment: before rendering on update page i am passing object of customer which is requested by user.. but then it submit updatecustomer form then in controller @modelAttribute creating new object and again setting all data in new object i want to set it into already persist object

Comment: `@modelAttribute` will just help you to get the data from UI, it will not give you existing destination entries. If you want them then make sure your form in front end is sending the destination entries also.

Comment: @JavedShhaikh, What you have tried, update your question and show us the code. Also print the data you are getting for destinations to make sure you have all the destination entries before calling hibernate update.

Comment: Just updated updateCustomer.jsp file.. in that i am setting destinations

Comment: Do you want the output while adding the destinations? right

Comment: here is the output before adding customer object into db.

Comment: Adding customer
destinations===>1.Mumbai
destinations===>2.delhi
destinations===>3.pune
18:58:53.764 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - opened session at timestamp: 14345477337
18:58:53.764 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - begin

Comment: I want to see the exact code which you have tried, can you edit your question and show the complete code related to this issue. In your post no where you are trying to get the Customer object from Hibernate session. Also as per your post where you are trying to print the destinations? because the message says `Adding customer destinations` so I am assuming you are printing in Add Customer code instead of update customer code.

Comment: here i am with updated code . i added new new line in my code problem is solve partially . now foreign key is not set to null. but when i am tring to update customer and remove destinations from customer then same thing not happen in my DB. DB till contain old data

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994015/removing-items-from-springs-autopopulatinglist . same as my issue. nothing is change